# How to display the top 10 values of a measure across the entire data in Business Object regardless of breaks?

Tags: business-objects

I need assistance with creating a report in business objects that display the top 10 values of a measure across the entire data, without being influenced by any breaks or grouping applied in the table, how can I achieve this using any function or formulas in business objects.

When I use the ranking function in analysis to show top 10, it will give me the top 10 for each group that’s not the desire outcome.  End up having more then top 10

Below is the desired outcome/layout:
Each salesperson is a section and only two groups in break.

Salesperson 1 (this person has more under Group A, but it’s not considered top 10 overall)
Group A
1
2
3

Group B
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

Salesperson 2
Group A
1
2
3
4
5

Group B
6
7
8
9
10

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can edit this structure to do top 5, top 10 or top 20 as you wish, note it also deals with duplicates;

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700)