# excel max values (what if there are more than one)

Tags: excel

In an excel file I have a list like this:

```
John Snow 12
Sam Smith 9
Angela Green 12
Peter Smith 11
Stephen Reed 8
```

I need to select all the cells names with max value.
If I use the following formula:

```
INDEX($A$4:$A$14;MATCH(MAX($AI$4:$AI$14);$AI$4:$AI$14;0))
```

it founds only the first max value, but what do I have to do if there are more than one max value?

Comment: Use the `FILTER` function. Something like `=filter(myRange,AI4:AI14=MAX(AI4:AI14))`

Comment: Or have a look here and give it a vote: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how old your version is, the following may work:

- Column A = Name
- Column C = the number

```
=INDEX(
    $A$1:$A$5,
    AGGREGATE(
        14,
        6,
        1 / ($C$1:$C$5 = MAX($C$1:$C$5)) * ROW($C$1:$C$5),
        ROW(A$1:INDEX($A:$A, COUNTIF($C$1:$C$5, MAX($C$1:$C$5))))
    )
)
```

If your version is even older and won't display all the results, you can try the following in some cell and fill down until you get blanks:

```
=IF(
    ROWS($A$1:A1) > COUNTIF($C$1:$C$5, MAX($C$1:$C$5)),
    "",
    INDEX(
        $A$1:$A$5,
        AGGREGATE(
            14,
            6,
            1 / ($C$1:$C$5 = MAX($C$1:$C$5)) * ROW($C$1:$C$5),
            ROWS($A$1:A1)
        )
    )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Both work, but both don't give me all results.

Comment: @Fabio Possibly did not properly adapt the formula to your real data. It certainly works here to return all of the MAX value'd names. "*don't give me all the results*" provides no useful information for me to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: @Fabio the formula posted above clearly works on my end, as well, what do you mean by **_Both work, but both don't give me all results_** can you post your expected outputs as well as also show what you mean by dont give me all results in a screenshot

Comment: Ok. I mean that the formula, in case I have to display more than one value, gives me only one, the first one result. Maybe It is the excel I use in office, because the excel I use on my home PC gives me all the max values correctly. Maybe I have to enable some options in order to get the "expanded" formula?

Comment: @Fabio When you used the second formula, did you fill down as instructed? Or did you just enter it into a single cell?

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld Yes, I didn't follow all you suggested, now if I fill down the other cells with the second formula it works very well. Thanks!! Now could I ask you how to do if I want the second max values? Following  my previous example how do I have to modify the formula if I want Peter Smith with value 11?

Comment: @Fabio With repeats and an old version of Excel, it is not a simple modification -- worth another question. But you can accept this answer since it seems to do what you want, even on the old version. When you post your new question, be sure to include the excel version in your tags.

Answer (score 1):

Use `FILTER` instead

```
=FILTER($A$4:$A$14;$AI$4:$AI$14=MAX($AI$4:$AI$14))
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm working with an old excel which doesn't support filter function.

Answer (score 0):

```
=INDEX(A:B, MATCH(MAX(B:B), B:B,0),1)
```

the A its the column of names, and B the column of values.

MAX(B:B) return the max value.

MATCH(max-val, B:B) return the row number.

INDEX(rowNumber, column-number) return the disired name.

Comment: When I tried it, your formula only returned a single line. He wanted to know how to return all of the highest valued lines.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `SEQUENCE` function available, you can try the following:

```
=INDEX(A1:A5,LARGE(IF(1-ISERR(SEARCH(MAX(B1:B5),B1:B5))=1, 
 SEQUENCE(ROWS(B1:B5)),0),SEQUENCE(COUNTIFS(B1:B5,MAX(B1:B5)))))
```

If not, then you can replace `SEQUENCE(ROWS(B1:B5))` with `ROW(B1:B5)`, assuming the input data is on the first row, if not, then: `ROW(B2:B6)-ROW(B2)+1`.

[image]

If you have also `UNIQUE` function available, you can use the following shorter approach:

```
=UNIQUE(INDEX( A1:A5,IF(1-ISERR(SEARCH(MAX(B1:B5),B1:B5))=1,
 SEQUENCE(ROWS(B1:B5)))))
```