# Excel Vlookup for multiple results

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I'm currently using the VLOOKUP formula to categorize my spending in Excel. However, I've encountered a situation where different transactions share the same name but fall into distinct categories. In such cases, I'd like the VLOOKUP to alert me when there are multiple possible categories for a transaction. I wish to have a dropdown list appear, allowing me to choose the appropriate category in these instances. If there's only one category associated with the transaction, I'd like the formula to display it directly without the need for a dropdown list.

I tried a lot of ways using chat gpt but nothing works

Comment: Do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700

Comment: Given how many people try Chatgpt and then come here, must prove we are smarter...