# EXCEL - Listing top 20 items from a range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of several hundred product codes (alphanumeric) and I'm trying to get a list of the top 20 i.e. the 20 items which occur the most.

I'm only able to make a formula that gets the single most popular item. I'm struggling to figure out how to extend it to include the second and third most popular etc.....

```
=INDEX(A2:A368,MODE(MATCH(A2:A368,A2:A368,0)))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could try: `=TAKE(UNIQUE(SORTBY(A2:A368,COUNTIF(A2:A368,A2:A368),-1)),20)`

Comment: Have a look at this as it was designed for earlier versions of Excel, give it a vote if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way as commented above:

```
=LET(α, A2:A368, TAKE(UNIQUE(SORTBY(α,COUNTIF(α,α),-1)),20)
```

---

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```
=TAKE(GROUPBY(A2:A368,A2:A368,ROWS,0,0,-2),20,1)
```