Index, match, need to return all matches, not just first
I am attempting to make adjustments to my dispatchers sheet I created for them to dispatch trucks. I have a new tab I created Samsara import to import data in a format that can be just copied into a csv to be uploaded to Samsara and create routes in accordance to where they dispatch trucks.
I cannot figure out a formula that does not retrieve errors due to data listed below it (filter formulas) or a way to index that catches the second location per driver name due to it always pulling the first match. Filter does do it, but there cannot be a space below to allow it to be placed.
=iferror(INDEX($F$3:$F,MATCH(N61,$C$3:$C,0))) is the formula I wanted to work. It searches the imported data within the F column that matches the row the driver name is listed.(returns the location that the driver is going to in order to load. This formula is listed within the M column in front of the drivers name.
The problem is, drivers are usually dispatched ahead of time for their second load, and to a different location, but it will only return the first match. I highlighted a few examples.
M19, the driver first load is going to Mudmasters WV to pick up a load. But his second location should be listing the Alvadore for his second location, but is listing Mudmasters instead due to it being the first match for that name.
I've tried many formulas, all with the same result. I've seen multiple ways to pull the second match, but I need to list both the first & second match to make the export possible.
I've made a copy of the involved sheets listed below.
Shared Sheet here

So you might want to check out the method I show here but consider I wrote this for Excel... https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700


You may enter this only in Cell_M3. Make sure to clear the existing formulas from M3 to bottom prior to entering this in M3 so as for this formula to expand freely:
=map(N3:N,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,chooserows(filter(F:F,C:C=Σ),countif(N3:Σ,Σ)))))




Also looks like you could try this single formula =tocol(C3:C,1) in Cell_N3


You sir. Are amazing! I am no newbie really to sheets, or formula's but I've been working on this for days (really weeks as time allows) I absolutely love you, and man that was quick!! Thanks!
