Match function only returns first occurrence
I want to make a top 10 of scores and when i use index and match function to match the scores with the codes, if more than one code has the same score it will match it to the first one only.
How do skip the first occurrence to match it to the next
I tried using an array with small and row functions but could find a way to apply the formula



the screenshot shows how data is presented after using index and match function, see how cells 3 to 5 have the same codigo matching the score(puntaje), except that other codes match the score as well but the function returns only the first occurrence

Use FILTER() and TAKE() function.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If you have an earlier version of Excel, then consider what I did here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700 , if it helps give it a vote...

the screenshot shows how data is presented after using index and match function, see how cells 3 to 5 have the same codigo matching the score, except that there are other codes that match the score aswell but the function returns only the first ocurrence

Assuming no version constraints per your tags

If your scores are unsorted
Create a Table from your data and Name it Scores

=VSTACK(Scores[#Headers],TAKE(SORT(Scores,2,-1),10))


If your data table is already sorted by Puntaje, then you can use:
=VSTACK(Scores[#Headers], TAKE(Scores,10))

Note that the above will only return the first ten (10) entries. If you want to return more than ten entries (because you have more scores that are in the top ten, then you should use:
=VSTACK(Scores[#Headers],FILTER(Scores,Scores[Puntaje]>=LARGE(Scores[Puntaje],10)))

If you have an earlier version of Excel, you can try one of the following:
=INDEX(Scores,-1+AGGREGATE(14,6,1/(Scores[Puntaje]>=LARGE(Scores[Puntaje],10))*ROW(Scores),ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,COUNT(1/(Scores[Puntaje]>=LARGE(Scores[Puntaje],10)))))),{1,2})

or, for even earlier versions:
=INDEX(Scores, IF(1, -1 + AGGREGATE(14, 6, 1 / (Scores[Puntaje] >= LARGE(Scores[Puntaje], 10)) * ROW(Scores), ROW(INDEX($A:$A, 1):INDEX($A:$A, COUNT(1 / (Scores[Puntaje] >= LARGE(Scores[Puntaje], 10))))))), {1,2})

The latter two may or may not have to be entered as array formulas.
To array-enter a formula, after entering
the formula into the cell or formula bar, hold down
ctrl + shift while hitting enter.  If you did this
correctly, Excel will place braces {...} around the formula.

thank you, this really helped. at the end I used a pivot table and got the answer i needed.
