VBA Loop function for duplicate values
I hope you could help me and point me in the right direction,
Is there a way to use loop function to return the value of each duplicate value in a list?
I’m new using VBA, I’m currently trying to find the best approach for the loop function within a column that contains duplicated values.
I want my for loop to check each duplicated value in the column and return its assigned values in a secondary worksheet.
For example my data consists in:
BP                 BP Code     Part number      Entry Date
Wess               BP0001      123534           6/18/2024
Dupl               BP0003      11123            6/18/2024
Wess               BP0001      113              6/01/2024
Wess               BP0001      23123            1/01/2022
SSm                BP0002      12223            1/01/2022

and so on;
were BP and BPcode "Wess" and "BP0001" are my main target and will be duplicated several times through the column; and the return value I need is "Part number" and "Entry Date"
I have tried the following code:
Sub match_Data()

Dim rSH As Worksheet
Dim sSh As Worksheet
Set rSH = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data")
Set sSh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Search Data")

Dim Bpartner As String, Pcode As String

  For a = 2 To sSh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Bpartner = sSh.Range("A" & a).Value
    Pcode = sSh.Range("B" & a).Value
    
    For b = 2 To rSH.Range("AQ" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
      If rSH.Range("AQ" & b).Value = Bpartner And rSH.Range("AP" & b).Value = Pcode Then
            
        sSh.Range("C" & a).Value = rSH.Range("AS" & b).Value
        sSh.Range("D" & a).Value = rSH.Range("AI" & b).Value
        sSh.Range("E" & a).Value = rSH.Range("AV" & b).Value
        sSh.Range("F" & a).Value = rSH.Range("AZ" & b).Value
        sSh.Range("G" & a).Value = rSH.Range("BA" & b).Value
            
        Exit For
      End If
    Next b
  Next a

End Sub

But right now the code is only returning the values of the first duplicated values found in the column (Sheet2 results):
BP                 BP Code     Part number      Entry Date
Wess               BP0001      123534           6/18/2024

I'm trying to explain the best I can, but please let me know if not, I hope you can help me on this.

Could you, please, add an appropriate tag to your question to indicate the language?  /// Never mind, apparently @CarstenMassmann has added them already.

Please edit your post to share what's the expected output. How do you organize duplicate records on the destination sheet?

Well, not vba but you may find it worth considering: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700

Your code logic currently exits the inner loop (Exit For) as soon as it finds the first match for Bpartner and Pcode. If you want to collect all duplicates, you need to remove the Exit For statement and modify the logic to append the values to the secondary worksheet.

You have shown us the Sheet1 data. Why don't you show us the expected result in Sheet2 in the same format?

If you need to be able to collect data from multiple matched rows you can append the returned values to each cell on the "search" sheet:
Sub match_Data()

    Dim rSH As Worksheet, sSh As Worksheet, a As Long, b As Long
    Dim Bpartner As String, Pcode As String, destCols, srcCols, i As Long
    
    Set rSH = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data")
    Set sSh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Search Data")
    
    'These two arrays map source columns to destination columns
    'You must have the same number of items in each array
    '  Col AS --> Col C, Col AI --> Col D, etc
    srcCols = Array("AS", "AI", "AV", "AZ", "BA")
    destCols = Array("C", "D", "E", "F", "G")
    
    For a = 2 To sSh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Bpartner = sSh.Range("A" & a).Value
        Pcode = sSh.Range("B" & a).Value
        
        For b = 2 To rSH.Range("AQ" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            With rSH.Rows(b)
                If rSH.Cells(b, "AQ").Value = Bpartner Then 'AQ1 is *relative* to Rows(b)...
                    If rSH.Cells(b, "AP").Value = Pcode Then 'two tests is more efficient than using `And`
                        'loop over items in column arrays and transfer/append data
                        For i = LBound(srcCols) To UBound(srcCols)
                            AddValue sSh.Cells(a, destCols(i)), _
                                     rSH.Cells(b, srcCols(i)).Value
                        Next i
                       
                    End If  'Pcode match
                End If      'BPartner match
            End With
        Next b
    Next a

End Sub

'Append value `addThis` to any existing value in `c`
Sub AddValue(c As Range, ByVal addThis)
    Dim v
    If Len(addThis) = 0 Then addThis = "[empty]" 'default for empty values
    v = c.Value 'read existing value
    c.Value = v & IIf(Len(v) > 0, vbLf, "") & addThis
End Sub


