Vlookup - getting answer from month upon month data
I have created a table with a drop down option to see a salespersons performance at any given month in the year.
I have one rating cell, which changes month on month, with it being either "poor", "good" or "excellent".
So I have data from Jan24 to Dec24, with sales persons names, and their rating month on month.
Would anyone know how I would do a look up to pull through what the monthly rating is for any given salesperson? For Ex, I want to see Dave Smith's rating in Jan-24, and then see what it is like in Aug-24.
EDIT: AS per example below, I want (on another tab) to be able to look up the employee, and what their rating was in a particular month

Can you share some sample data?

Try using FILTER

Or index() with match() and match(), like vlookup(), can be set to have multiple criteria - see examples already on here.

If the month is in A1 and the name is in B1 of Sheet2, you could e.g. in C1 use =XLOOKUP(1,(Sheet1!A2:A16=A1)*(Sheet1!B2:B16=B1),Sheet1!C2:C16,"No match") to  return the (1st) matched rating. To return multiple ratings like in the case of the Jun-24 - Joe Smith combo, you could 'similarly' use =FILTER(Sheet1!C2:C16,(Sheet1!A2:A16=A1)*(Sheet1!B2:B16=B1),"No match"). Additionally, you could wrap the latter in UNIQUE(?) to remove duplicates and/or in TEXTJOIN(", ",,?) to get a comma-separated list in a single cell.

Well, put some data together as you only gave an image.
Used index() with match(), check out the match as it is using two columns.

Data validation is used in E3 and F3 to select the month and employee.
Then if you need to find duplicates as well, consider something like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700

thank you so much for your answer! Spot on, exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much
