Display only the Top5 values from SORT function



A
B
C




100

900


300

800


900

700


500

600


400

500


200




700




800




600




120






In Cell C1 I want to sort Column A in a descending order and only show the Top5 results. 
So far I have been able to develop this formula:
=SORT(A1:A10,,-1)

However, it displays the entire results. How do I need to modify it to only show the Top5?

Try: =TAKE(SORT(A1:A10,,-1),5) why is that 800 not included?

Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700

@Mayukh Bhattacharya: I edited it. Now the 800 is included.

Try using SORT() with TAKE()


=TAKE(SORT(A1:A10,,-1),5)


Perhaps from your older posts, per your comments, you don't have access to LAMBDA(), so I can, conclude you won't be having access to TAKE() as well, as both are released for same versions and built of Excel, hence, here is an alternative.
=INDEX(SORT(A1:A10,,-1),SEQUENCE(5))


