Excel Data Extraction
I need help with Excel to display data based on drop-down selections. I have a table with "Name" and "Gender." How can I set it up so when I select "Male" or "Female" from a drop-down, it shows all names matching the chosen gender?

What is your exact version of Excel? You can use FILTER() if you are on latest version of Excel. For Excel 2013 and later use AGGREGATE() function and for older versions you need combination of few functions with array entry.

Seems that a pivot table would be the simplest option

Please edit your question to show what you have tried, and where you have run into problems. It would also help to familiarize yourself with how this site works by taking the Two Minute Tour. Then read the HELP pages for information as to How to Ask a Good Question, and How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

You could do something like this, edit to suit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Here/below refers:
Assuming you have office 365 compatible version Excel, you can achieve this with a combination of named ranges and Choose/match functions(1)
Setup:

List names and respective genders (sorted by gender, any direction)
Create named ranges 'Name_Male' and 'Name_Female' for the respective groups(2)


Referencing relevant cells as follows:

Validation list:
1) Forward looking:
Enter Gender (cell F3), and create the following validation list function in the cell of your preference (here, adjacent viz. G3) as follows:
=CHOOSE(MATCH(F3,HSTACK("Male","Female"),0),Name_Male,Name_Female)

Voila!



2) Backward looking:
Despite numerous pitfalls, validation lists are immune to 'circular references' In other words, at the same time as being to create a list wtih all the names that correspond to a particular gender type, you can create another validation list to display the appropriate gender for any given name ☺
Here is how:

Clear the Error and Message Alert checkboxes so that you can type in any value not just an entry from the drop down list in cell G3 (name col).
Enter the following into the validation list function in a cell of your preference (here, F3):


=CHOOSE(MATCH(G3,$D$3:$D$11,0),$C$3,$C$4,$C$5,$C$6,$C$7,$C$8,$C$9,$C$10,$C$11)




Notes:

(1) Per comments, validation lists are exceptionally flawed in that they kick-back errors if you enter a working function that you would expect Excel to be able to handle (sometimes it will return the error message whilst displaying the range of a #Spill! function - so it is presumably evaluating the function, just not operating correclty!). Functionality varies by Excel version which makes the matter more complex.
(2) - Care to be taken in creating named ranges based upon functions like filter, etc. because even these can lead to issues in validaiton lists (despite operating correctly within the named range!)
