How to return top X unique values in a column by the condition in another column
I am trying to return top selling companies for different conditions (size) and top selling companies' price in the table F:J. I need to do this for multiple reports with thousans of rows of data, so any automatization/formula would highly be appreciated.
example

I tried different things like combining soring formulas etc. but none of them worked.

Try this, give it a vote if it helps. I did this as an example - my original works across several sheets. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640367/4961700

Show us what you did so far.

Use FILTER() with SORT() function.
=CHOOSECOLS(INDEX(SORT(FILTER($B:$D,$A:$A=F2),2,-1),1),1,3)


