# Extracting top 5 maximum values (column wise, not row wise)

Tags: excel

This questions answers something similiar: 
[Extracting the top 5 maximum values in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528624/extracting-the-top-5-maximum-values-in-excel)

I'm looking to perform this operation for my data when it's organised in rows rather than in columns. How would I adapt the formula to do this?

Sample data:

```
Score   9   2   3   5   9   6   9   9   9
Player  P1  P2  P3  P4  P5  P6  P7  P8  P9
```

Comment: Do you want the top 5 _including_ duplicates or excluding them?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Including them please! It needs to account for ties, much like the formula in the link I posted. However, we can assume there won't be more than 5 top values in my actual data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the formula from your link in `B4` and auto-fill to the right:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$J$2,MATCH(1,INDEX(($B$1:$J$1=LARGE($B$1:$J$1,COLUMNS($A4:A4)))*(COUNTIF($A4:A4,$B$2:$J$2)=0),),0))
```

[image]