# Google Docs / Excel : Extracting the top selection based on two parameters

Tags: excel-formula

Good Afternoon,

I was browsing on how to use various excel functions such as vlookup or similar to vlookup and was fortunate enough to find the following page.

[Extracting the top 5 maximum values in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528624/extracting-the-top-5-maximum-values-in-excel)

Is it possible to use a similar formula to create a list of the top people using two parameters? For example, using a similar set of data but added a third column for level. I would want the formula to find the top 15 members based on one parameter then another 7 based on a second set of parameters without allow copies in the 22 person list that is generated.

This link is the google spreadsheet. I hope this allows members to copy paste to attempt to answer this question.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XtvCHpKLSup1weQ3zQNl6E9utupGOGYVIUxhaq4EgnA/edit#gid=749714188

Thank you again.