# Top Name based on the average score in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to find the top 5 names which scored the highest number based on the average.

```
Name    Score
Ann        15
Jess       20
David      10
John        9
Ann        10
David      10
Jon         2
```

So based on the above data the top scorer should be found by taking the average score value and returning the name.

Is there a formula in excel?

Comment: Check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528624/extracting-the-top-5-maximum-values-in-excel

Comment: but in that every player is scored a different value

Comment: Have you tried anything? Or are you just looking for someone else to give you an answer?

Comment: @AnnaliseAzzopardi - try it ;)

Comment: @DavidZemens - No...

Comment: @Vityata - I have tried it but when I copy and paste the formula in the attached link you have done it is return #N/A

Comment: @AnnaliseAzzopardi - take a look at the other answers as well. Especially the one of `Nathan Fisher` should work for your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to the article recommended by Vityata, that formula would work for your needs if you simply add an averageif formula in column C, and then change all references to the new column. The average if formula in column C should be:

```
=AVERAGEIF($A$2:$A$8,$A2,$B$2:$B$8)
```

The adapted formula in column D would look like:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$8,MATCH(1,INDEX(($C$2:$C$8=LARGE($C$2:$C$8,ROWS(D$1:D1)))*(COUNTIF(D$1:D1,$A$2:$A$8)=0),),0))
```

Also in the article, a commenter asked how to adapt the formula for a sum of scores (basically the same as your average), and the original poster recommended a pivot table. But if you want to avoid pivots, just add an Average column and be done with it.