# Listing the top 5 values of a range and their matching titles

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max

I have a sheet with a large amount of data where each row has a title for a project (F6:F244) and then in a column a bit further along it has the Total Hours spent on each project (V6:V244) along the same row. Is it possible to find the 5 largest values from the Total Hours column and show them in another part of the sheet with their respective project in an adjacent cell?

So far I have been able to get a single project by finding the maximum value in the column by using: =INDEX($F$6:$F$244,MATCH(LARGE($V$6:$V$244,1),$V$6:$V$244,0))

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528624/extracting-the-top-5-maximum-values-in-excel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the top 5 values should go in 5 different cells. In this case why not use the same formula you already had, but look for 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th highest?

```
=INDEX($F$6:$F$244,MATCH(LARGE($V$6:$V$244,1),$V$6:$V$244,0))
=INDEX($F$6:$F$244,MATCH(LARGE($V$6:$V$244,2),$V$6:$V$244,0))
=INDEX($F$6:$F$244,MATCH(LARGE($V$6:$V$244,3),$V$6:$V$244,0))
=INDEX($F$6:$F$244,MATCH(LARGE($V$6:$V$244,4),$V$6:$V$244,0))
=INDEX($F$6:$F$244,MATCH(LARGE($V$6:$V$244,5),$V$6:$V$244,0))
```

Comment: I didn't truly understand how the formula worked so thanks for the help! It works perfectly and i'm just using a separate formula to get the highest values in the adjacent cells.

Answer (score 0):

Just enter the below formula, wherever you want the output to be,

```
=INDEX($F$6:$F$244,MATCH(LARGE($V$6:$V$244,ROW(1:1)),$V$6:$V$244,0))
```

and drag it to 5 cells for getting the maximum 5 values. If you want the same for maximum 10, drag it for 10 rows. Hope this helps.