# Is there a way to get multiple max and mins from a column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max, min, worksheet-function

I have to sort some data for a job. I have a script that pulls two columns of data from a larger spreadsheet, then sorts the data by the first column (smallest to largest) then the second column (largest to smallest). I want to so for example I have...

```
1 29    
1 28    
1 27    
1 24    
2 33    
2 18    
2 17    
3 42    
3 29    
3 19
```

and I want it to output...

```
1 29    
1 24    
2 33    
2 17    
3 42    
3 19
```

What I've been doing is manually deleting these rows so I can then use my next script which does some other manipulation to it. Any way to automatically do this?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528624/extracting-the-top-5-maximum-values-in-excel) could get you started

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use a pivot table to do this?

Answer (score 0):

*While...*

- `MIN(range)` returns the smallest value from `range`, *similarly*
- `SMALL(range,n)` gets the `n`<sup>th</sup> smallest item from `range`.

*...and while...*

- `MAX(range)` returns the largest value from `range`, *similarly*
- `SMALL(range,n)` gets the `n`<sup>th</sup> smallest item from `range`.

---

***Therefore, for example***...

- `MAX(A1:Z9)` is the same as `LARGE(A1:Z9,1)`.
- The **5<sup>th</sup>** largest value would be `LARGE(A1:Z9,5)`.

---

## More information:

***Office Support:***

- **[`SMALL` Worksheet Function](https://support.office.com/article/small-function-17da8222-7c82-42b2-961b-14c45384df07)**
- **[`LARGE` Worksheet Function](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/large-function-3af0af19-1190-42bb-bb8b-01672ec00a64)**